# Apache Phoenix - Count query returns more than 100k rows, but SELECT query does not return any row

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-phoenix, apache-spark-3.0

Using **Apache Spark 3**, I manipulated some CSV data, stored in a dataframe, with the intention of sending it to HBase.

The data is successfully sent using `JavaHBaseContext`'s `bulkPut()` method.

However, in **Apache Phoenix**, using a plain `SELECT` query, I get the message 'No rows selected'.

[image]

When I run SELECT `count(*)` query, I get:

[image]

Meanwhile, HBase's shell allows to ensure the availability of data as expected.

What could be the problem?

Comment: might be the schema is broken.

Comment: @Lamanus My colleague discovered that when the table is created with COLUMN_ENCODED_BYTES = 1, rows are not displayed. When the table is created with COLUMN_ENCODED_BYTES = 0, the rows are created but the columns are not aligned with data.